# Object duplicates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My question is how can I pass from this :

```
const array = [
    {name: "Bline", score: 95},
    {name: "Flynn", score: 75},
    {name: "Carl", score: 80},
    {name: "Bline", score: 77},
    {name: "Flynn", score: 88},
    {name: "Carl", score: 80}
]
```

to this array of objects using javascript:

```
[
    {
      name: 'Bline',
      data: [95, 77]
    }
    {
      name: 'Flynn',
      data: [75, 88]
    }
    {
      name: 'Carl',
      data: [80, 80]
    }
    ]
```

I have tried using the duplicate but nothing so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should iterate over your array and set `name` as `key` and `score` as `value` in an array manner in an **object**:

```
let result = {}
for (let item of array) {
  if (!result[item.name]) result[item.name] = [item.score]
  else result[item.name].push(item.score)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the expected result by first grouping the data with a reduce function.

```
let grouped = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
    r[a.name] = r[a.name] || [];
    r[a.name].push(a.score);
    return r;
}, {});
```

And then format it to what you wanted.

```
let formated = Object.entries(grouped).map(([key, value]) => {
    return {
        name : key,
        data: value
    }    
})
```